# Global variable capture and math in PHP

Tags: php, variables, math, web, global-variables

I will keep this short in order to not take too much of your day, but I have been working on a certain project in PHP for some time now, and I am finally coming to a close on it. However, I seem to be having trouble grasping this concept of the global variable and how to successfully use it in the way I want and I am not quite sure why.

My program essentially does this:

- Takes in a bunch of IDs and forms groups
- Creates a page for them which has a report of all the information, allows for download once a button is pressed
- Takes the member total current when the button is pressed, and translates that into the global variable which will now define another option on the page (member change since last report) by taking that and subtracting the total value from it

Some examples of my code starting from the definition start page

```
$GLOBALS['TheDifference']; //defines the variable for later use
```

On the actual viewing pages for the groups, keep in mind this statement is in a foreach, so it will repeat each time for each group

```
        $MemberDifference;
        if ($MemberDifference == 0) {
                $MemberDifference = $FailureMessage;
        }
//the above will be blank at first due to nothing being in it
        $pastmembers = $GLOBALS['TheDifference'];
        if ($pastmembers == 0) {
            $pastmembers = $TotalMembers;
        }
//this activates when the variable becomes filled
        $MemberDifference =  $pastmembers - $TotalMembers;
```

And finally, when the button on the report pages are clicked:

```
$GLOBALS['TheDifference'] = $TotalMembers;
```

The issue is essentially, my MemberDifference variables are always 0, and they do not seem to save as I hope they should (from the code directly above this, 0 turns into whatever that variable is, which will then end up subtracting the new TotalMembers from PastMembers).

I hope I explained this mostly, maybe even with too much information. PHP isnt my best language and while I feel I am missing something very simple, I cannot for the life of me wrap my head around it.

Thank you all in advance!

*Edit, the reason I need global variables is because this program essentially runs over many different pages, at least 5 in total, and the global variables are the only ones I really know as a way to do this. If there is a better way, feel free to let me know!

Comment: Try echoing out your variables along the way to see what they're set to.

Comment: As I understand, you pass `$TotalMembers` to `$pastmembers` and then try to do `$pastmembers - $TotalMembers`. Here your  `$TotalMembers` and `$pastmembers` are same. Thats why its showing 0. For global variable u can use session for more easy way.

Comment: If global variables worked the way you seem to expect, every visitor of your site would share the same global variable. Surely not what you'd want.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is not how web-pages work, when the page is loaded, the script on the server has already finished and your variables have been removed.

If you need the state to persist, you should not use global variables (you never need these by the way...) but a session or a database.

To use a session, you need to start every script with `session_start();` and then you can use the `$_SESSION` array to store your data.

Comment: I see! I will try this out and see how it works out, thanks for the quick answer!

Comment: This is actually exactly what im looking for! One last question if you possibly know,Since im doing most things in a foreach, how would i use this $_SESSION array to apply differently to each group?

Comment: @Twitchy I'm not sure what you mean, it's an array and you can organize it as you need. So you can use multiple levels to group information and loop over sections.

Answer (score 0):

It would appear you are trying to persist information about a visitor across multiple visits. (Two pages constitute two visits as per HTTP semantics.)
In that case a good solution would be to learn and use the [PHP Session](http://php.net/manual/en/book.session.php).

Shared totals would need to make use of some sort of persistent storage like files or an SQL database.